# How to auto-run an application at boot on CentOS?

Tags: centos

I've got an app installed on my CentOS server. In order to run it I have to run these two commands.

```
[myserver local]# cd /usr/local
[myserver local]# #ppbed start
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can get this app `ppbed` to start at boot time?

I should note that `ppbed` is also located in my `/etc/init.d/` folder, but it's not executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you've already got your script in the `/etc/init.d/` folder, you still have to add it to the chkconfig.

This is how I did it

```
[myserver local]# chkconfig --level 345 ppbed on
```

That's it. Now it runs on startup.